# How to call a privileged method with a jquery plugin. Boilerplate jquery design pattern

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I followed this common design pattern for a boilerplate jquery plugin, and I am having trouble calling the privileged method this.service() inside the constructor from anywhere in the prototype.  How can I call this.service() from inside the prototype, not just in the init of the prototype?

Overall, What I am trying to do is to be able to access a variable in this plugin that will only be affected and changed within this instance of the plugin.  Should this variable be placed somewhere else?  The variable is named variableToAccess in my code.  Maybe I am coming at this all wrong.  Thanks.

plugin in is called as follows

```
$('article').comment();
```

here is the plugin

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    // Create the defaults once
    var pluginName = 'defaultPluginName',
        defaults = {
        propertyName: "value"
    };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        var variableToAccess = false;//<----should this be somewhere else?
        this.service = function() {
            variableToAccess = true;
        };
        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {
        init: function() {
            Plugin.prototype.doSomething();
        },
        doSomething: function() {
            this.service()//<----doesn't work
        }
    }

    $.fn["comment"] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName,
                new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    }

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be incorrect here, but I don't believe you should be calling doSomething() via Plugin.prototype.doSomething().

this.doSomething(); should invoke the method. Please see below:

```
function Plugin( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;
    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    var variableToAccess = false;
    this.service = function() {
        variableToAccess = true;
    };
    this.init();
}

Plugin.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        this.doSomething();
    },
    doSomething: function() {
        this.service();
    }
};

$.fn.comment = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if ( !$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName) ) {
            $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName,
            new Plugin( this, options ));
        }
    });
 };
```